# Prove that $\log_2 n$ is not bounded polynomially from below, need 2nd step

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, bounded-variation

i.e. that $\log_2 n\not\in\Theta(n^x)$ for any $x > 0$

i shall not use induction on $x$ ( as $x = 1$ base case etc)

my guess is :
i use the def. of big theta:

$$ 0≤c_1·n^x \le \log_2 n \le c_2· n^x $$

where do i go from here?

Comment: hey martini, how did you add superscripts to n^x? i don't know how to do it!

Comment: You can use LaTeX markup on this page, to write $n^x$, just write `$n^x$`

Comment: ERJAN, since you've indicated you know the lower bound fails, what have you tried in order to prove it? Perhaps a better question: for which $n$'s should it stand/fail?

Comment: by def of big theta, n => n_0, n_0 > 0

Comment: So, then, what tools do we have to see whether there exists some $c_1>0$ (note, $c_1\neq 0$ by necessity) such that for all 'really large' $n$ we would have $c_1 n^x\leq \log n$? (I dispensed with the logarithm base; it makes no matter, since every logarithm is a scale of any other, and our constant $c_1$ will 'absorb' the difference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this is simple actually, prove by contradiction:

assume it is true, then big-theta means it is in between c1 * $n^x$ and c2 * $n^x$.

in other words, if we take limit of f(n) / g(n) -must be nonzero, finite( non infinite) and must exist

take limit:

lim (lgn / $n^x$) as n -> inf. = lg(inf) / $n^(inf)$ = inf.

which is a contradiction. done!